# Creating Visual Studio AddIn run error

Tags: visual-studio, add-in

This has been happening to me over and over for every single AddIn project I make.
I create the AddIn projet from the template wizard and work on it, coding and debugging for a few hours and then all of a sudden I get:

Error   1   Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Project1.dll" to "bin\Project1.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Project1.dll' because it is being used by another process.

Does anyone know what is this about?
Happening in VS2008 and VS2010.

Thank you

*Edit: I have found a workaround by closing all instances of VS, deleting the Project1.dll file, selecting NO when VS asks me if I want to delete a reference to the AddIn when opening VS instance again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually came across this today and it took me forever to figure it out.  For me I was creating an Addin that automatically loaded when Visual Studio starts.  The way I fixed it was by going to:

Tools -> Add-in Manager

Then **uncheck** the **first checkbox** near your addin.  Keep the "**Startup**" checkbox **checked** to continue having debugging of your Addin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. I will try it out.

Comment: No problem.  After you do the above you might have to close all instances of VS and restart VS.  But after that you should be good.